# UWP, I can't check the data in the ListView

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I searched for a bluetooth device, put data into the Contact class, and tried to display it on the ListView, but the data doesn't seem to be bound.

In the `OnAdevertisementReceived` function of MainPage.xaml.cs,

by using `TagListICON.Source = Contact.GetTags();` I connected to `TagListICON` of `CollectionViewSource` in MainPage.xaml.
I put a break on `TagListICON.Source = Contact.GetTags();` to check if the data is well entered, but I don't know why.

Can you guess what's what?

Thank you.

Comment: The ListView control has no data. Your data is stored in the Contact entity class. Does the bluetooth transmit data entity class fail to receive?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function where the data is updated.

```
private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher 
      watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
```

.
.
.

```
         await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
              TagListICON.Source = Contact.GetTags();
              TagDataResource = Contact.GetTags();

              Debug.WriteLine("Current Time : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
              for (int i = 0; i < TagDataResource.Count; i++)
              {
                  var item = TagDataResource[i];
                  Debug.WriteLine("CodeNum : " + item.CodeNum + " Mac : " + item.MacAddress + " Data : " + item.Mdata + " Name : " + item.Name + " RSSI : " + item.RSSI);
                  test = item.MacAddress;
                  testTxtBlock.Text = test;
               }
               this.Bindings.Update();
         });
```

> this.Bindings.Update();

is used to update data changes so that they are bound.